# What is this creature? Where can it be found?

Tags: species-identification

I recently received the picture below from a friend and began to worry. Does it really exist? What type of creature is it? What habitat does t live in and what is its range?

[image]

Comment: A probability always depends on a priori such as typically where do you live, do you often drink from rivers, etc...? You should probably just ask "Is this a real thing?", "what is it?" and "where does it live?" Note that you can  improve the post by removing unnecessary informations such as how many people liked the post or what time it was when you took the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've edited the question and the picture to suit your request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The creature in the man's hand is a baby eel. Giveaways: it has fish eyes and the flattening of the tail. The lower right picture suggests it's a vertebrate (i.e. not a worm.)

[image]

Exactly [which eel](http://thelifeyouandineverknew.blogspot.com/2010_06_01_archive.html) it is is unclear, but you can read more about it in the linked article. Indeed, your first picture appears in the article.

> These transparent wonders are not a species, but rather they are the second stage in the life cycle of a number of eel species in the family Anguillidae. This particular specimen is an American eel, Anguilla rostrata. For the rest of the post I'll focus on the life cycle of this species for simplicity's sake.